# Problems installing vqv/ggbiplot

Tags: r, pca, devtools, ggbiplot

I was able to install successfully `library(devtools)`, but when trying to install:

```
install_github("vqv/ggbiplot")
Downloading GitHub repo vqv/ggbiplot@master
Error in utils::download.file(url, path, method = method, quiet = quiet,  : 
  cannot open URL 'https://api.github.com/repos/vqv/ggbiplot/tarball/master'
```

didn´t work!

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: That url works for me, so it's on your end. I suggest you try it again. It it fails again in R, try it in your browser. If it succeeds, then your computer's firewall is blocking R's access to the internet. If it fails in your browser, consider your firewall or one on your network.

Comment: thanks, it works now!

Comment: I still have some issues, I tryed
````

Comment: Yes? You tried what?

Comment: `install.packages("remotes")`
`remotes::install_github("vqv/ggbiplot")`
BUT GOT AN ERROR
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rcpp’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp’
Error: Failed to install 'ggbiplot' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘Rcpp’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: The same happens with: `install_github("vqv/ggbiplot")`

Comment: You likely need to reinstall or update `xcode`.